# How to place the current locations in leaflet open street map in angular application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, leaflet, angular8

I have an angular application and I have placed the map using leaflet open street map.I need to place the current latitude and longitude for that map.(has to be change according to the location).
**My  Question is how to place the current coordinates for map using leaflet map.**

And my component.ts code is

**.component.ts**

```
 var  map = L.map('map').setView([13.0827, 80.2707], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

    
} ).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current location coordinates using navigators

```
ngOnInit(){
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setGeoLocation.bind(this));
   }
}

setGeoLocation(position: { coords: { latitude: any; longitude: any } }) {
   const {
      coords: { latitude, longitude },
   } = position;

   const  map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 3);

   L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>contributors'
    } ).addTo(map);
}
```

dot this in your App.component.ts when ever the application loads setGeoLocation function triggers initially and updates the leaflet map.

Hope this works!.